# inkscape - combine svg elements into combined path

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

I have a hexagon based on one common side, repeated. The single side is a `<g>`roup of a `<path />` and transformed `<use />`.

**I want to fill the inside of this virtual hexagon, but am unable to.**

Indeed the hexagon is many `<use />` tags grouped and transformed, so this not working right-off-the-bat makes sense. I have tried doing a path `union` with all objects selected, and have tried using the `Combine path` feature.  However, in either case, the path entities in the object explorer remain independent, and filling any object still fills individual path segments, not the net hex shape as a whole.

Below you can see the many objects:

[image: svg path and use objects]

Even after trying to exec "Combine path", filling still looks like:

[image]

What I'm after is to be able to combine those paths, and fill with a raster image:

[image]

I have a few helpful references:

1. [inkscape svg, as shown above](https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/12a61eb7c85f152f4268bf4ce07b0713)
2. [raw web svg output, from which above svg is derived](https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/bf855b28d69b6ab1553627622cd83c6d)
3. [my fun little tessellation app, which inspired this problem :)](https://cdaringe.github.io/tessl/)

Any tips or tricks would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a closed path, combined with the circle in the middle.

A quick and dirty method is to use the Fill Unbounded Areas Tool (aka the Bucket fill tool).

Zoom in on the shape to make it large. The bucket fill tool in Inkscape depends on the on-screen rendering of the shape, then click inside it with the tool.

Example

[image]

The longer method would be to join the two end nodes of each segment to the other end nodes of the other segments, to create a closed path.

Using the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>F2</kbd>, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select two adjoining segments, then click and drag the tool over the end nodes to be joined, and hit the Join Selected Nodes button in the Control Bar along the top. Repeat for all segments until you have one closed path. Don't forget to join the two final open end nodes to make a complete closed path.

[image]

Next, select the circle and click *Path > Object to Path*, then reverse the direction of the path by clicking *Path > Reverse*.

Select all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then click *Path > Combine*

Now you can set the fill attribute of the completed shape.

Comment: If the end nodes of each sub-path overlap, then you can select all nodes with ctrl-A, then join all end-nodes with Shift-J, and it should work. [related answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/76738/68027)

Comment: @Juancho, yes that would save some time.

Comment: incredible.  thank you so much. can't wait to try this!

Comment: Nodes don't need to be selected individually, just select them all. The closest ones will be joined. However, this is a great case for the 'rotate copies' LPE - and then, after conversion to path, some Boolean magic (i.e. Path > Union, Path > Break apart, Path > Union, then subtract the center circle).

Comment: for others whose SVG have <use /> nodes, inkscape at 0.x would not convert <use /> nodes to <path /> objects, but 1.x does.  upgrade, such that Object to path works!

Comment: @cdaringe <use tags in an SVG are clones.  If your artwork has these then it is something caused by the software or method that was used to create them, not Inkscape.  If there are clones you'd need to unlink the clones. Inkscape 0.92 can unlink clones, and once unlinked they will become paths.  As of posting, note that currently Inkcape 1.x is not yet a stable release.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use LPE fill between many.

- creat new geometry (this does not matter it gets overwritten)
- add LPE fill betwen
- copy all your geometry you want to fuse
- past it into the field in path effect panel

Comment: sounds cool.  LPE ... LivePathEffects ya?  whats the path effect panel?

Comment: http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects.html