# inkscape extension - covert use node to path node

Tags: inkscape, script

a couple of weeks ago i learned:
[inkscape - combine svg elements into combined path](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/131847/inkscape-combine-svg-elements-into-combined-path), and would now like to do it programmatically.

my document has `<use />` elements, which in inkscape 1.x show path entities with the path tool, so, i figured i'd first try and just coerce the use into a path:

`if el.TAG == 'use': self.svg.replace(el, el.to_path_element())`

but inside of elements.py, on the to_path_element call, it throws with `AttributeError: Can't find attribute Use.path`.

ideas on how to convert `<use />` to `<path />`?

Comment: <svg:use  elements in Inkscape are clones.  You can release clones in Inkscape using *Edit > Clone > Unlink clone*

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to figure out how to do it programmatically through the python interface

Comment: Then that would be a coding question rather than a graphic design question.  You might be better to post this on Stack Overflow. If you want, you can flag your own question to have a moderator migrate it for you.

Comment: ported to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587940/inkscape-extension-covert-use-node-to-path-node